Build succeeds but error occurs on Amplify: next-intl-split with edge runtime in Next.js
I'm having a problem running my Next.js version 14 project on Amplify. Both yarn dev and yarn build && yarn start work correctly on localhost, but when I try to deploy it on Amplify, the build completes successfully, yet I encounter an error when accessing the website.
enter image description here
Here the logs
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1') 2024-11-05T05:40:11.891Z at t.loadI18nTranslations (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/606.js:1:197838)
And here another error "Currently, Amplify doesn't support Next.js Edge API Routes."
I think my Next.js application might be running on the edge runtime on Amplify, but I'm not sure. In the edge runtime, I can't access certain packages like "fs" or "path", which are used in loadI18nTranslations code with next-intl-split.
export default getRequestConfig(async () => {
  const lang = await getUserLocale();
  const locale = lang || 'pt';

  const messages = loadI18nTranslations('./locales/', locale);

  return {
    locale,
    messages,
  };
});

I’ve already tried many things, including changing the path to the app's absolute path, but it doesn't work.
const lang = await getUserLocale();
  const locale = lang || 'pt';

  const messages = loadI18nTranslations(`${process.join(process.cwd())}/locales`, locale);

  return {
    locale,
    messages,
  };

Here is the documentation I followed to run next-intl-split: next-intl-split
And here is the next-intl documentation: next-intl
I'm still not sure if this issue is related to the translations, but I strongly suspect it might be.
I hope I made myself clear, and I appreciate any help. Thank you!
